# String Boolean error java

Tags: java, string, boolean

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong over here,

```
(Util.parseBoolean((String)request.getAttribute("testVal"), false))
```

I am getting this error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean incompatible with java.lang.String
```

If what value I get from the request would do this. Thanks

Util just looks for request value and if it is y or true than sends back boolean value true. but my issue is when it goes to this line its throwing exception saying that error so I am not able to know whats happening

Comment: Nobody knows what your Util class does.

Comment: What is `Util.parseBoolean`? What is `request.getAttribute`?

Comment: I think he meant `Boolean.parseBoolean`

Comment: @user161...etc Advice: delete this question and re-start new one that you show us enough code. These downvotes will affect your reputation.

Comment: Util just looks for request value and if it is y or true than sends back boolean value true. but my issue is when it goes to this line its throwing exception saying that error so I am not able to know whats happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an exception and you don't understand what's causing it, a good first step is to isolate exactly where it is happening.  There are a lot of things happening in that one line of code, so it's difficult to know exactly what operation is causing the error.

Seeing the full stack trace of the exception might help, since it would give an idea of where you are in the execution path when the exception occurs.

However, a simple debugging technique is to break that one line with many operations into many lines with fewer operations, and see which line actually generates the exception.  In your case this might be something like:

```
Object o = request.getAttribute("testVal");
String s = (String) o;
boolean b = Util.parseBoolean( s, false )
```

If the cause suggested by Shivan Dragon is correct, then the exception would occur on the second of these three lines.

Comment: I am getting an object value of false but when I am trying to convert Obj to string its throwing that error. Can you suggest me what can I do to get rid of that error. Thanks

Comment: Skip the middle step, @user1617247. You've already got a boolean (looks like). Just cast the return value of `getAttribute` to a boolean, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this code: `request.getAttribute("testVal")` returns a Boolean, which cannot be cast to String, hence the (runtime) exception.

Either:

- check for code that populates the request attribute "testVal" with the boolean value (something like `request.setAttribute("testVal", Boolean.FALSE)`) and replace the value with a String

or

- Don't cast the value to String in your code, and don't use what seems to be a utility class for building a boolean value out of a String (*)

(*) which, btw, the Boolean class can do all by its lonesome self, no need to make your own library for that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: This is a bold assumption from your part

Comment: Agreed, the question is poorly redacted (at best). I'm taking a wild guess here.